# how to remove duplicate array elements using hashmap in java

Tags: java

How to remove duplicate elements in an array using HashMap without using hashset in java...
Below code describes removal of duplicates in array..

Now i need to write using hashmap for generating key and value pairs

```
import java.util.*;

class TestArray{

public static void main(String arg[])
{

ArrayList<String> wordDulicate = new ArrayList<String>();

    wordDulicate.add("chennai");
    wordDulicate.add("bangalore");
    wordDulicate.add("hyderabad");
    wordDulicate.add("delhi");
    wordDulicate.add("bangalore");
    wordDulicate.add("mumbai");
    wordDulicate.add("mumbai");
    wordDulicate.add("goa");
    wordDulicate.add("calcutta");
    wordDulicate.add("hyderabad");

    ArrayList<String> nonDupList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<String> dupIter = wordDulicate.iterator();
    while(dupIter.hasNext())
    {
    String dupWord = dupIter.next();
    if(nonDupList.contains(dupWord))
    {
        dupIter.remove();
    }else
    {
        nonDupList.add(dupWord);
    }
    }
  System.out.println(nonDupList);
}
  }
```

Comment: A simpler way to to what you did is to do `new ArrayList<String>(wordDuplicate)`. What values do you want to store?

Comment: I need to store as a key/value pair using HashMap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a HashMap will prevent you from entering duplicate keys, the same way as HashSet. Actually, many implementations of HashSet just use a HashMap under the hood.

So you can do:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String s : WordDuplicate) 
  map.put( s, s );
```

Now you can access the key/values just like a HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

A `HashSet` is implemented in terms of a `HashMap` anyway. If you specifically want to use a `HashMap`, use it the same way as `HashSet` does: use a dummy constant `new Object()` as the map value everywhere.

Comment: I don't get your comment. My answer explains what to do **without using HashSet**. It is almost exactly the same advice as in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Stack;

public class stackdupes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
        int[] arr= {1,2,3,3,4,5,5,7};
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(set.add(arr[i]) == true)
            st.push(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(st); 

    }   
}
```